# laravel place abstractions in model instead of repository

Tags: laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

I am just trying to figure out if I want to use the repository pattern.
The three advantages that I could find:

```
1. Testability (repositories can be injected into the controller)
2. Abstraction (complex eloquent queries can be refactored into repository functions)
3. Decoupling (enables me to replace the persistence layer)
```

However, aside from point 3 I don't really see it that clearly.

```
1. I can just as well inject the model (or a mock for testing)
2. I can also abstract the queries into functions and place them into the model instead of a repository.
```

So assuming that I don't care about being tied to Eloquent I do not really see the point of using Repositories. I appreciate any arguments to change my mind.

Comment: I'd recommend you to put all data related logic into models if you're using Eloquent. If you'll do that you still follow repository pattern and using a repository package has too many disadvantages and doesn't give you any really important advantages. If you're using Query Builder or raw SQL queries, use the repository package.

Comment: Repository Pattern will help you to replace the ORM as a whole and use some other OM like Doctrine. If you create repositories by injecting Eloquent Model Class would be one level flexible in terms of replacing eloquent ORM with some other ORM in future. But if you just wanna break up the Eloquent into one extra abstraction then it would be worthless rather just an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view and experience, you can use Eloquent as your repository layer.

For point 2, you can create scope methods to be able to use along with normal Eloquent queries

```
$users = User::whereHasACarOfColor('yellow')->where('active, true)->get();
// ...
public function scopeWhereHasACarOfColor($query, $color) 
{
    return $this->whereHas(function ($cars) use ($color) {

        return $cars->where('color', $color);

    });
}
```

I had different experiences with repository layers in Laravel in the last months:

1. Since I wanted to re-use code, I had to create a lot of similar method, `getUsersWithYellowCars()`, `getUsersWithYellowCarsOrderedByName()`...
2. If you decide not to create so much specific methods, you will end up with a bunch of methods with a lot of parameters

   ```
   public function getUsersWithCars($color, $orderBy, $orderDescOrAsc, $paginate...)
   ```
3. Sometimes you need to pass the model to the repository to interact with them instead of interacting directly with it

   ```
   $students = $usersRepository->getStudentsForProfessor($professor, 'name', 'ASC');
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   $students = $professor->getStudents()->orderBy('name')->get();
   ```
4. After a while the code doesn't look as clean as expected (check example in 3.)

Also, want to say that Eloquent is already an ORM, if you decide to change from MySQL to SQLite, you doesn't have to change anything on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your list of benefits one by one:

> 1. Testability (repositories can be injected into the controller)

This is true. Later in your question you say you can just as easily inject a model into your controller so what's the point? The point is that if you use an interface to define your repository methods, you can have your concrete repository which you use in production code to actually query the eloquent models, while using a "Fake" repository that implements the same interface for testing. I do this quite frequently, where my "Fake" implementation just uses a Collection to hold the models I am testing. That way, your tests run faster and you don't have to worry about migrations in your controller tests. It also keeps you from having to interact with the database in your unit tests. **I am not saying it is inherently bad to test against the database, but you should avoid it where possible**. Using a repository helps you speed up your tests where you don't *need* to interact with the database. By type-hinting the Repository *interface* in your controller, you can pass in a fake implementation for testing and bind a real implementation in a Service Provider for your production code.

> 2. Abstraction (complex eloquent queries can be refactored into repository functions)

This is up to you. The problem with the repository pattern in Laravel is that no matter how hard you try, your models are tied to the database. There's no way around it. The chances of you scaling your app and re-using the repository is next to zero, so this isn't necessarily a bad thing. Business logic should not be in your models **or** repositories anyway, so the heart of your app (if designed properly) will still be abstracted from the framework. In a true repository pattern, your queries are defined in the repository. But since Laravel's models are tightly coupled to the database, it doesn't really matter where you put this logic. In fact, Laravel has some nice Eloquent features that may make it more desirable to put this logic straight in your models. Where repositories really shine in Laravel is what I brought up in your first point, being able to somewhat abstract from the database in your tests.

> 3. Decoupling (enables me to replace the persistence layer)

This is the main point of the repository pattern and exactly what makes point #1 possible. Of course, passing around Eloquent models means that wherever the model is, so is the database. That's just something you have to live with with Active Record.

---

Expanding on @Lloope's answer, the other benefit is having your complex queries defined in one spot (either your models or a repository) to avoid having code like this littered throughout your codebase:

```
$professor->getStudents()->orderBy('name')->get();
```

And instead use something like this:

```
$students = $usersRepository->getStudentsForProfessor($professor, 'name', 'ASC');
```

The problem with writing Eloquent queries all around your app is that as requirements change, you have to update those queries everywhere in your app. This could just be once in your controller, or in dozens of different parts of your app. A `getStudentsForProfessor` method on a repository (or even just your Eloquent model) is much easier to maintain down the line. It means that your other objects don't need to worry about what `getStudentsForProfessor` does or how it functions. They just know that it will return a collection of students for the given professor. A repository helps you organize your query logic in one place. Once you define this interface, or *contract*, your other objects can rely on it to do what it says. As query requirements change, you update the implementation in one place rather than all across your app. The contract is still the same. This allows for much more flexibility than writing Eloquent queries everywhere.

Comment: what I'm trying to say with the example is that using your models as repository layer, you can drop the method on them and use it directly, so in the example it's de professor who has the method `getStudents` and after that you can order them or paginate or whatever. If you do the same on repositories, you should create `getStudentsForProfessor`, `getStudentsForProfessorOrdered`, `getStudentsForProfessorPaginated`, `getStudentsForProfessorOrderedAndPaginated`, and so on

Comment: I see. I'll edit my answer then. Sorry for misunderstanding :)